# Could not build module 'UIKit' on simulator but not on phone

Tags: ios, swift, simulator

I received following errors when trying to build my project on iphone simulator 5 and 6 and 6 plus. I tried to clean and rebuild again but did not work. I had no clue why this is happening. Because when I plug my phone in, it will run correctly on the phone.

The most important errors here are somehow `UIKit` and `QuarztCore` both unfounded.

Can anyone look into this? How do I resolve this issue so that I can run my app on simulator! Thank you!

```
/project-folder/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAMetalLayer.h:7:9: 'Metal/MTLPixelFormat.h' file not found   
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UICollectionViewLayout.h:11:9: Could not build module 'QuartzCore' 
/project-folder/Parse.framework/Headers/PFConstants.h:27:9: Could not build module 'UIKit' 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Headers/SKStoreProductViewController.h 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Headers/SKStoreProductViewController.h:9:9: Could not build module 'UIKit' 
/project-folder/hatchpic-Bridging-Header.h:8:9: Could not build module 'Parse' Failed to import bridging header 
'/project-folder/hatchpic-Bridging-Header.h' Failed to import bridging header 
'/project-folder/hatchpic-Bridging-Header.h' Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is not StoreKit. Maybe 'CAMetalLayer' cause it requires A7 device (not simulator).

**Updated:** 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1

You can find APIs that are not supported in simulator in this link. Apparently, Apple has removed StoreKit from this list. So maybe, the reason is not StoreKit. Maybe 'CAMetalLayer' cause

```
API Limitations
Within iOS Simulator, there are some limitations to the APIs and features, including:

Apple Push Services
Privacy alerts for access to Photos, Contacts, Calendar, and Reminders
The UIBackgroundModes key
iCloud document syncing and key-value storage support
Unsupported frameworks include:

External Accessory
Media Player
Message UI
Event Kit
In UIKit, the UIVideoEditorController class
```

Comment: I fixed it by testing in the phone, magically errors automatically goes away, but it comes back if i want to use simulator. So should I re-install my simulators?

Comment: You can't. The problem is: you use APIs that cannot run in Simulator (check the list above)

Comment: I get it. I do have Push Services and UIBackgroundModes key in info.plist. But I don't have other features. But I don't know if these two are causing the app failed to launch tho. Since `CAMetalLayer` has nothing to do with these two features. Moreover, I don't have this `CAMetalLayer` used in any of my code, strange..